# Mass evolutions and lucky eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

When I do a lot of evolutions at once without going back to the main screen it shows up the xp you gain all at once. Ex. If I evolve 2 zubats in a row it shows up as +1000 xp when I return to the map.

If I have a lucky egg active do the xp I gain double as I evolve each pokemon or only at the end when I return to the map? This is important because if I return to the map after the lucky egg expires I might not get the double xp bonus.

Comment: If there is a bug where the exp and the lucky egg multiplier don't get applied till you leave the 'pokemon' tab and return to the 'world map' it would be great to know and point out to Niantic, though I doubt they would make such an error in their code. I am not sure if there is a way to check your exp without first going back to the map though.

Comment: This was also a concern of mine, I didn't want to risk it and so kept going back to the main screen just in case. As it turns out I had a few minuets to spare after evolving everything so it didn't really matter.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have done this multiple times, and I know that the experience is applied appropriately. I kept count of the amount of Pokémon I evolved and how many did/did not gain the XP bonus.

This experiment was carried out by not exiting the menus until I had completed the evolutions, as well as timing the applicable duration of the XP boost. Additionally, all of these Pokémon (and their evolutions) had already been added to the Pokédex, so no additional bonuses were gathered (however, from additional testing this is also appropriately applied).

Pokémon evolved under the effects of the Lucky Egg:

- 12 Pidgeys
- 4 Rattatas
- 2 Zubats
- 1 Oddish
- 1 Paras
- 1 Caterpie
- 2 Weedles
- 1 Slowpoke

Total XP: **24000** (1000 XP per Pokémon)

After 35 mins (to make sure that the effect had ended) of applying the Lucky Egg - Pokémon evolved without the Lucky Egg

- 2 Pidgeys
- 1 Rattata
- 1 Psyduck
- 1 Goldeen

Total XP: **2500** (500 XP per Pokémon)

Upon exiting to the map, I levelled up, and was greeted with a counter of **26500** XP.

Comment: The Lucky Egg lasts 35 mins? I thought it was 30... Does it depends on the level you are?

Comment: It is only 30 mins, they are showing how the XP is effected differently with and without the lucky egg. Even though they didn't return to the main screen, the effect of the lucky egg had been granted to the Pokemon they had evolved whilst having the lucky egg active, but not to those that where evolved after the 30 mins.

Comment: @Momop. I waited 35 mins to *make sure* that the effect of the egg had expired.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely goes up as you evolve them. I used a lucky egg and evolved at least 7 pokemon, and went from the beginning of level 13 to 14 and a half when I came back out. Even though it only lists one evolutions worth of xp, it gives you all the xp. Unless there's an occasional bug for some and not others, this has been my experience with lucky eggs and evolving

Comment: But the question is was the boost in xp after your lucky egg had run out?

Comment: You mean if you're evolving pokemon, and the egg runs out while you're in the screen, will you're experience from all that evolving be doubled? Of course it would. The experience is doubled upon reward, not return to map. When you have a lucky egg on and catch a pokemon, the experience listed after the catch is doubled. No return to map necessary.

Comment: The question is when is the xp rewarded? Do you have evidence that shows the xp gained is calculated as soon as a pokemon is evolved?

Comment: No amount of experimenting is going to give you that answer, as your xp bar isn't showing until you exit to the world map. The only way to get a real, actual answer would be from niantic

Comment: lol you could easily try. just wait close until the end of a lucky egg. evolve a pokemon. wait 3 minutes, return to screen and check your gained exp. its either 500 or 1000.

Comment: I can guarantee its going to be 1000. If it didn't, xp would be rewarded upon map return, which is just a silly design choice. Also, when you gain a huge amount of xp, and come back to the world map, its not as if your bar moves THEN. Your bar has been moving while you're in the menu, the number just reports it.

Comment: "this HAS to be this way or it would be a silly design choice". I'm with you on it being a silly design choice. But that does NOT mean that this is how it works. A lot of games have silly design choices.